# Domain to apache, subdomain or subdirectory to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, subdomain, directory

I set up an `Apache2.2` and `Tomcat7` Windows Server. Now I would like to use the domain for the apache and a subdomain or a subdirectory for the tomcat webapps. But I don’t know how to configure the `httpd.conf`.

At the moment the `httpd.conf` looks like:

```
<IfModule !mod_jk.c>
    LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_jk.c>
    JkWorkersFile conf/workers.jetty.properties
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel info
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost servername:*>
    ServerName servername
    ServerAdmin administrator@servername.com
    JkMount /* jetty
</VirtualHost>
```

My idea was to change the `VirtualHost` to `sub.servername:*` but this doesn’t work.

How could I use a subdomain or directory for the webapps? At the moment, every call will me directed tomcat. My `tomcat` runs on the port `8081`. Maybe edit the `server.xml` from tomcat?

It would be awesome, if someone could help me. Greetz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`httpd.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  domain.com
    ServerAdmin sysadmin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog logs/domain.error_log

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**`mod_jk.conf`**

```
LoadModule          jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile       /etc/httpd/conf/workers.jetty.properties
JkShmFile           /var/log/httpd/jk.shm

JkLogFile           /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel          info
JkLogStampFormat    "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      sub.domain.com
    JkMount         /* jetty
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

About how to configure AJP service, you need to edit at least these files: httpd.conf of Apache HTTPd, worker.jetty.properties of mod_jk and server.xml of Apache Tomcat.

Look at worker.jetty.properties file if is it defined "jetty" worker and pointing to 8081. Also you need to define on server.xml the AJP connector (by default AJP1.3 it's pointing to port 8009)!